# What does "Clean Clothes" do?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

When using a Rest Stop, one of the options is to Clean Clothes.  The description on it is "Clean all your equipment".  What does that actually do, though?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing, it's just aesthetic.

> While out adventuring in the lands of Aionios, your party's character models will slowly start accumulating dust and grime. Cleaning their clothes at a Rest Spot gets rid of the dirt, giving your party members clean clothes before resuming travel.
> Do note, this feature is entirely for immersion purposes. Whether clean or grimy, the story and gameplay of Xenoblade Chronicles 3 will not be directly affected by this mechanic.

According to [Game8](https://game8.co/games/Xenoblade-Chronicles-3/archives/383694).